# Opengl: GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24 not defined

Tags: opengl, gcc, mingw

Good afternoon,

The setup:

- I've never done any gl programming.
- I'm attempting to compile some opengl
  driver code that compiles in other environments.
- I'm using mingw on windows in the hope that using gcc on both linux and Windows would make my life easier...

The problem:
The second parameter of the following isn't defined anywhere:

```
glRenderbufferStorageEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, tex->getWidth(), tex->getHeight());
```

I'm guessing this code is old and it's deprecated? What should I do about the above issue?
Is there a good reference on the opengl API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might want to grab a copy of [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) to make your life easier on the extension front.  It should have up-to-date versions of all the GL #defines in case whatever glext.h you have is stale.